# jQuery draggable table elements

Tags: jquery, css, drag-and-drop, html-table

jQuery's `draggable` functionality doesn't seem to work on tables (in FF3 or Safari). It's kind of difficult to envision how this *would* work, so it's not really surprising that it doesn't.

```
<html>
  <style type='text/css'>
    div.table { display: table; }
    div.row { display: table-row; }
    div.cell { display: table-cell; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/latest/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/latest/ui/ui.draggable.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".row").draggable();
  });
  </script>
  <body>
    <div class='table'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>Foo</div>
        <div class='cell'>Bar</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>Spam</div>
        <div class='cell'>Eggs</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr class'row'><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td></tr>
      <tr class='row'><td>Spam</td><td>Eggs</td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm was wondering a) if there's any specific reason why this doesn't work (from a w3c/HTML spec perspective) and b) what the right way to go about getting draggable table rows is.

I like real tables because of the border collapsing and row height algorithm -- any alternative that can do those things would work fine.

Comment: Do you have an extra space in each of your selectors?  There should be no space after each "div" and before the dot.  For example, your first selector matches elements with class="table" inside of a div...

Comment: Fixed, thanks, but it didn't make a difference. :(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have truly tabular data, you should stick with table indeed.

And if you want to drag rows *within* a table, this **[JQuery + "draggable row table" library](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/)** works perfectly in FireFox3

Comment: Whoops -- fixed the table location.

Comment: don't know if intentional but your answer totally rhymed :)

Comment: @AndresIlich I tried to take a look at this answer again, / Hoping to catch in it a refrain / That would illustrate some facility / in an English writing ability / But I found the effort quite vain. (http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/the-basics-of-limerick-composition/)

Comment: @VonC, may i request you to have a look at a jquery question on a different topic here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137404/jquery-find-div-class-name-at-a-certain-position-while-scrolling ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed unfortunately, jquery isn't my forte (as my tags illustrate: http://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc?tab=tags). you would better try and contact one of the gurus: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/topusers

Answer (score 35):

There is a way to make table rows draggable with JQuery UI too.
All you need to do is set the helper option to a function returning a new div with a table inside that will host the row you are dragging like:

```
helper: function(event){
return $('<div class="drag-cart-item"><table></table></div>').find('table').append($(event.target).closest('tr').clone()).end();
},
```

Thx to David Petersen for the tip: http://blog.petersendidit.com/post/drag-table-row-to-a-div-with-jquery/

Comment: good technique! when using this, don't forget that any `drop` callbacks on your `$.droppable()` elements can still reference the `ui.draggable` property in order to target the original row element. so you don't need to sacrifice any functionality while using a slightly funky helper (hope that makes sense)

Comment: Is there a good method which doesn't clone tr element? Now it shows both original and cloned table row, being a little bit confusing for the user

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible, but what about adding a css class to the source row and gray it out or something while you are dragging?

Answer (score 11):

Just in case anyone makes the same mistake I did:

If you want to be able to reorder TRs inside a table by dragging them around, .sortable is what you need rather than .draggable

Just me?

Answer (score 3):

This is kinda late, but today I found **[html5 drag'n drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop)** works fine with `<tr>` element. All you need to do is enable it `<tr draggable="true">` and register the events

```
dragstart
drag
dragenter
dragleave
dragover
drop
dragend
```

I found this article very helpful http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

!!Be aware that there is a flaw in this html5 API that the event will be fired when you hover over the child elements even though you are only interested in the parent element. Hope html5rocks people will fix it soon.

Answer (score 1):

I made this work by using JqueryUI with the following:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".sortable").sortable({
    revert: true
  });
});
```

```css
table td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody class="sortable">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Five</td>
      <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Six</td>
      <td>some text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also set css `tr.ui-draggable-dragging {display: block}` - this way one can drag the rows, however, their coordinates are poorly calculated. I haven't found a good solution for this issue yet.