# jQuery dragging (reordering) table rows between multiple tbodies

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm great with CSS but I largely suck at jQuery. We all have our limitations...

OK with that admission out of the way I'll begin. We have a "favourite products" table, which you can sectionalize into categories (eg, Booze, Sheep, Spoons). Each category is a . Each row (excluding the ) is a product.

I want to enable a user to drag and drop (reorder) the table rows, even between tbodies. I've looked at [Table Drag and Drop (DnD)](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/) plugin for jQuery but was disappointed to find that it doesn't really support dragging between tbodies - and hasn't been updated for quite some time.

Here is the basic table structure:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Favourite</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Spoons</th> <!-- secion title, not draggable -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wooden Spoon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Metal Spoon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Plastic Spoon</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Nuclear Bombs</th> <!-- seciont title, not draggable -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>US Nukes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Soviet Nukes</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm going to need to turn of the "dragability" of certain rows such as the first row in the  - this being the section title.

Is there a better version of a jquery plugin out there that can do what I need? If you can find a better plugin please share and win my "favourite person of the week" award.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Your going to want to use **jQueryUi's sortable plugin** and then use the option

```
connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
```

to connect the different table bodies.

the plugin is designed for lists, but it does work on tables, mostly.  I've used it with success on a table before.

here's the link to the documentation on jquery ui's sortable:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

EDIT:

you'll also want to use the items option to specify that certain rows are sortable

```
items: 'tr:not(.dontIncludeMe)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into jQuery UI's [droppable widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)? I'm wondering (since I haven't played around with your specific problem yet) if you could set your `tbody` as droppable and your `tr` as draggable.  Or possibly add some classes to each to be able to specify that certain rows (non-title rows) are draggable...

*UPDATE*: more research turned up [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307882/jquery-draggable-table-elements), which links to [this other article](http://blog.petersendidit.com/post/drag-table-row-to-a-div-with-jquery/) about dragging table rows.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm making promising progress. Me and jQuery! I definately need to practise more.

Answer (score 1):

you can turn off the dragability in case od table dnd plugin by specifying

```
<tr class ="nodrag nodrop">
  <th>Favourite</th>
</tr>
```

class nodrag nodrop will not allow drag and drop

and

class nodrag will not allow it to be dragged i hope it helped.