# Draggable and Droppable jquery UI within same table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on an MVC application and I have faced a situation. When i googled it i didnot find anything about this. The situation is as follows:-
I have a table as follows:-

```
<table>

        <thead>

            <tr>

                <th>Test1</th>
                <th>Test2</th>
                <th>Test3</th>
                <th>Test4</th>

            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

                <tr>

                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>2</td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>3</td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>4</td>

                </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>
```

I want to make a row draggable and drop it after another row or before some other row.

How can I do that using jquery?

Comment: Possible solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591264/can-table-rows-be-made-draggable) (first hit when googling 'jquery draggable table row')

Comment: Nopes. This is moving from one place to another. Not in the same table.

Comment: take a look at this link http://isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/