# jquery swap table cells by drag and drop

Tags: jquery

I think the jquery sortable plugin is great:

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

Unfortunately, I need to use table cells, where you can swap table cells by drag and drop only if the destination cell is in the same column. I think the only way this can be done is if you give all table cells for a column the same class name:

```
<table id="sortable">
  <tr>
     <th>column1</th>
     <th>column2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <td class="column1">column1</td>
        <td class="column2">column2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="crm-data">
        <td class="column1">column1</td>
        <td class="column2">column2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And then try to contain the drop feature to an element with same class:

```
  $('#sortable td.column1').draggable({
    containment: ".column1"
  });
```

This does not work at all. The td is no longer draggable.

What is the best way to drag and drop table cells within a contained column?

Comment: Try this?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3592057/1981678

Comment: @briansol That example you post is simple. It uses table rows. THere's already a plugin for that. But here I need to drag and drop table cells within columns, not rows. Also that example doesn't swap.