# Customize table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to design a customize table layout. For example after adding data my table is created. Now I am showing column name in one column and column data in another column, I want to add functionality if I drag one row to third column, Then column structure will be modified and that row will be added to new column.

For example: This is my table: [jsfiddle.net/x8L57md2/](http://jsfiddle.net/x8L57md2/)

code:-

```
            <tr>

                <td>Name</td>
                <td> Ankur </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td>jaipur</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>State</td>
                <td> Rajasthan</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Country</td>
                <td>India</td>
            </tr>

          <table>
```

If I move state column to right side of ankur(name) then another table column will be created and append it to table with data.

Like this: [jsfiddle.net/ttzr2ezh/](http://jsfiddle.net/ttzr2ezh/)

code:-

```
           <table border="1">

            <tr>

                <td>Name</td>
                <td> Ankur </td>
                <td>State</td>
                <td> Rajasthan</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td>jaipur</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Country</td>
                <td>India</td>
            </tr>

          <table>
```

Comment: Please provide code. Putting links in a code block is not an acceptable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Dragging `tr` elements is a little tricky. Here's a modified version of [a clever approach from a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591264/can-table-rows-be-made-draggable/3592057#3592057). You can view a fully working JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xwyoe0y9/

```
// make sure you reference jQuery and jQuery UI

$(document).ready(function() {

    var dragInfo = {};

    $('table.rearrangeable tr').draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        start: function(event, ui) {
            dragInfo.tr = this;
            dragInfo.helper = ui.helper;
        }
    });

    $('table.rearrangeable tr').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var tr = ui.draggable;
            $(this).append(dragInfo.tr.innerHTML);

            $(dragInfo.tr).remove();
            $(dragInfo.helper).remove();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes, same what i want. But it's not working correctly. Suppose i drag state row to left side of name, Then it will create a new column ( as per your example), After that i am moving country row to bottom of state(bottom of newly created column) then it's not adding to the new row. So may be some modification needed or        we need to use different approach.

Answer (score -1):

Look up [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#default), there is simple functionality for making a UI item 'sortable'.

With this new library installed you just need to label the rows or individual elements and in Javascript make them 'sortable'.

HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr class='makeSortable'>
      <td>Element1-Title</td>
      <td>Element1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='makeSortable'>
      <td>Element2-Title</td>
      <td>Element2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='makeSortable'>
      <td>Element3-Title</td>
      <td>Element3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".makeSortable" ).sortable();
    $( ".makeSortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is trying to accomplish. Look at their second code block (the resulting HTML).

Comment: Just working with the information I've read. Things tend to get blurred in the explanation. Either way, this will work for sorting and dragging element around, whether the style is what he's looking for or not. Some minor tweaking and he shouldn't have any trouble.

Comment: This would be "teach a man to fish" if OP wanted fish, but OP wants a steak

Comment: Then where are your answers? :)

Comment: Really? Is that your argument? If somebody asks about A, you answer about A, not about B and then act "offended" if somebody points it out. Now, answering your question: I don't have an easy answer to OP's question; I can imagine a complex one using jQuery-UI drag-and-drop (not sortable). But I wouldn't publish it until a) I have it at least sketched, and b) I make sure it is what OP is asking about.

Comment: Good fish/steak analogy. This particular problem is a little beyond what you can easily glean from the jQuery UI documentation, so I went ahead and provided a working example. Although, the OP should have at least shown _some_ attempt to solve it on their own first... anyway, I'm guessing they'll still have a good deal of work left to make this solution cover additional use cases, such as dragging a pair of previously moved cells back to a new/different row...

Comment: Then godspeed, and no insult. I should expect reproach when trying to help others. And I am unable to comment and find out more about the issue in question, so it makes it a little hard so I'm helping in any way I can. Hopefully OP can see the practical in what is there. I'm answered A, to the best of my ability. I apologize it's not to your liking, I'm new. So thank you for your comment I will try to teach people to fish for steak instead. Thank you Alvaro. :)

Comment: I once got my answer downvoted by the OP even though it fulfilled every requirement they had listed, because it failed to fulfill a requirement that they _also wanted but didn't specify_. I guess they wanted a psychic to predict whether they wanted fish or steak for dinner to begin with.

Comment: This is not what i want.

Comment: You guys are very encouraging :)