# Can table rows be made draggable by attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

### Please note, I know of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591264/can-table-rows-be-made-draggable). I do not want to use jQuery-UI.

---

I can simply add this to most any element, and it will be made draggable:

```
<... draggable="true">
```

However, on `<tr>` elements, this does not seem to work.

```
<div draggable="true"></div>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr draggable="true">
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Can `<tr>` elements be made draggable *without* any plugins, as the `<div>` can?

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/439pvedh/)

Comment: HTML5 Draggable is not available on table rows. You would have to use something else like jQuery to do this.

Comment: here's a draggable library that might help http://draggabilly.desandro.com/