# Making each row of a jqGrid draggable

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, draggable, rows

I want to make each row of my jqGrid draggable. My goal is when I drag a row from one jqGrid and drop it on other jqGrid row (I want the data on which row the drop event happened), some backend operation needs to be performed.

So far I have tried as below.

JQuery code:

```
$("#gridtable").jqGrid(
                {
                    datatype : "json",
                    datastr : values,
                    colNames : [ 'Name','Age'],
                    colModel : [ {
                        name : 'name',
                        index : 'name',
                        shrinkToFit: true
                    },
                    {
                        name : 'age',
                        index : 'agee',
                        shrinkToFit: true
                    }],
                    rowNum : 10,
                    rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
                    autowidth : true ,
                    pager : '#gridpager',
                    sortname : 'name',
                    viewrecords : true,
                    sortorder : "desc",
                    caption : "JSON Example"
                });
var rows = $('#gridtable' tbody tr);
rows.each(function(i){
(this).draggable{
//some options here
}
```

But this code is not working. The rows are not draggable.
Please help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**jqGrid** provides a default functionality to achieve drag and drop between two grids using `gridDnD`.
See Document [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods)

Calling convetions:

```
jQuery("#list").gridDnD(options);
```

or using the new API

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('gridDnD', options);
```

#### See detail example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/9980/)

Now moving into your code and **jquery-ui draggable** issue. See this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591264/can-table-rows-be-made-draggable) for better explanation.

#### And a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/9982/).