# Jquery: Drag and drop rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

first I will explain the code:

**VIEW**

```
<table class="table">
            <thead style="color:white">
              <tr>
                <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByIdAsc"></span></a>ID<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByIdDesc"></span></a></th>
                <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'slug','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderBySlugAsc"></span></a>SLUG<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order',['field' => 'slug','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderBySlugDown"></span></a></th>
                <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByOrderAsc"></span></a>ORDER<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByOrderDesc"></span></a></th>
                <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByPublicAsc"></span></a>PUBLIC<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByPublicDesc"></span></a></th>
                <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="color:white">
              @foreach ($projects as $key => $project)
                <tr>
                  <td>{{$project->id}}</td>
                  <td>{{$project->slug}}</td>
                  <td>{{$project->order}}</td>
                  <td>{{$project->public}}</td>
                  <td><a href="{{ route('admin.projects.show', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a> <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to make it draggable (by rows)

I see code like this but doesn't work:

```
$('.sorted_table').sortable({
  containerSelector: 'table',
  itemPath: '> tbody',
  itemSelector: 'tr',
  placeholder: '<tr class="placeholder"/>'
});
```

Know how to do it?

If have any question please let me know it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Aren't libraries available for that?

Comment: do your table have the `.sorted_table` class? As far as I can tell, I only see the class `.table` on it.

Comment: @Daniel well, in code I just copy the code from website, but in my code is `$('.table')`

Comment: Which plugin are you using for sorting? How come `$(..).sortable`?

Comment: @tilz0r Sure, I'm trying to find one to make it easier. Also I want to change the project->order if I change the position with the drag. Also i'm checking vue.js to make it maybe

Comment: FYI, his question is typical *give me a tutorial or a book* which is off topic on SO.

Comment: I'll assume you're using jQueryUI to allow table sorting

Comment: I think this one will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591264/can-table-rows-be-made-draggable

Comment: I prefer call it: Help me if you know how to do it ;) @tilz0R

Comment: @Daniel I'm trying to follow this guide: https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#docs

Comment: @Kevin mm.. I checked the code and doesn't help me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Daniel maybe we can make a chat. You are available?

Answer (score 0):

View must look like here:

```
<div id="tabs">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="current">
            @include('cms.public.views.partials._messages')         
            <div id="table1">
              <table class="table">
                <thead style="color:white">
                  <tr>
                    <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByIdAsc"></span></a>ID<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByIdDesc"></span></a></th>
                    <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'slug','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderBySlugAsc"></span></a>SLUG<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order',['field' => 'slug','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderBySlugDown"></span></a></th>
                    <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByOrderAsc"></span></a>ORDER<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByOrderDesc"></span></a></th>
                    <th><a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByPublicAsc"></span></a>PUBLIC<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByPublicDesc"></span></a></th>
                    <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="color:white">
                  @foreach ($projects as $key => $project)
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{$project->id}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->slug}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->order}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->public}}</td>
                      <td><a href="{{ route('admin.projects.show', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a> <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  @endforeach
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();

$("tbody").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone"
}).disableSelection();

$("#tabs ul li a").droppable({
    hoverClass: "drophover",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        var tabdiv = $(this).attr("href");
        $(tabdiv + " table tr:last").after("<tr>" + ui.draggable.html() + "</tr>");
        ui.draggable.remove();
    }
});
```